# position relative to the bottom of parent

Tags: html, css, position

I've two menu that show on hover of an icon. I'd like both menu to show on the bottom left of the icon when hovering. However the menu are different sizes and I can't manage to make them be under the other while keeping the same classnames.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ar78354/1/)

```
<!-- one item menu-->
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10rem;margin-left:3rem;">
  <div class="icon">
  + hover here
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menuItem">
     item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- multiple items menu-->
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10rem;margin-left:6rem;">
  <div class="icon">
  + hover here
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menuItem">
     item
    </div>
        <div class="menuItem">
     item
    </div>
        <div class="menuItem">
     item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.menu{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1rem;
  right:5rem;
  opacity:0;
  color:white;
  background:grey;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:default;
}
.icon:hover + div{
  opacity:1;
}
.item{
    cursor:default;
}
```

In other words I'd like the right menu to start under "+ hover here".

Comment: *`on the bottom left of the icon `* where' that exactly? Immediately below the `+` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
  bottom:-1rem;
```

use

```
  top:1rem;
```

like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1ar78354/2/)

Answer (score 0):

another solution is, move bottom:-1 propery from .menu to .item

```
.container{
      position:relative;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .menu{
      position:absolute;
      right:5rem;
      opacity:0;
      color:white;
      background:grey;
      display:inline-block;
      cursor:default;
    }
    .icon:hover + div{
      opacity:1;
    }
    .item{
        cursor:default;
        bottom:-1rem;
    }
```